# How to configure htaccess for non www domain?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I want to configure htaccess file. I use domain withoud www, also my domain is indexed in search engines mydomain.com and not www.mydomain.com
when i go to www.mydomain.com it doesn't redirect to mydomain.com
I found that code in htaccess  file. Is it correct? what should i add them?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 2):

Log into your cPanel
Find the Files category and click on the File Manager icon.
Click Settings at the top right corner.
Choose the document root for the domain you are working with and be sure the checkbox next to Show Hidden Files is checked. Click the Save button.
file-manager-show-hidden
Look for the .htaccess file and right click on it. This brings up a menu. Find and click on the Edit option.
file-manager-htaccess
You are now in the text editor. Place either selection of code in the file and click on the Save Changes button at the top right corner of the screen. Be sure to replace 'example.com' with your actual domain name. NOTE: do not place both selections of code in the file as it will cause an error.

## Force www:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/ $1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

## Force non-www:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/ $1 [L,R=301]
```

Now, when you type in your domain name with either www in front or not, it should display as you have set it in the .htaccess file.